# computing the maximum point-wise distance of both CDFs

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, dice, cdf

I have 2 [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) and have to find the maximum pointwise distance. I created histograms and plotted both. The values are generated by a random function which takes the sum of two random numbers 1-6 for 100 times, similar to two dice. But, I can't manage to find the maximum distance between two lines on the plot.

So, on the first run I have a list of 100 observations, `dicesum=: {1: 5,  2: 8, 3: 7, ....,  100:4}`.

1 to 100 is the number of spins and the right side is the sum.  With this code I generated the histogram:

```
keys,values = zip(*dicesum.items())
plt.hist(values, bins=30)
plt.gca().set(title='Frequency Histogram', ylabel='Frequency');
plt.show()
```

The histogram:
[image: histogram]

Now I plot the CDF with this code:

```
x = np.sort(values)
y = np.arange(1, len(x)+1/float(len(x)))
plt.plot(x, y, color='b')
plt.xlabel('Sum')
plt.ylabel('CDF')
plt.show()
```

[CDF plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvRvd.png)

Now, plot 2 observations in the same plot to see their differences:

[image: 2 observation plot]

And now I want to get the max distance they have, so in which point they are furthest from each other.

Comment: By CDF I assume you mean Cumulative Distribution Function?    Can you not just subtract the two and look for the maximum?  e.g. something like `imax = np.argmax(np.abs(y1-y2))`.  (That'll tell you at which point, then you can just evaluate at that point to get the max distance.)

Comment: Yes i mean Cumulative Distribution Function?  so as you can see on the last picture there are 2 lines of 2 seperate observations . now i have to find in which point they are farther with each other . i tried what you suggested but seems not working  on my case . thanks

Answer (score 1):

For measuring the distance between two such CDF plots as described in your criteria, you can use [Kolmogorov–Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) test for equality between the two distributions. or you can use maximum point-wise distance of both CDFs. I think it might help.